# Show that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}\left(f(x)+f'(x)\right)=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

How to show that $\lim_{x \to +\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=0 $ implies $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x)=0$?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/42848/).

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* If, $L = \displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}$ and since $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} e^x = \infty$, L-Hopital suggests,

$\displaystyle L = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{(e^xf(x))'}{(e^x)'} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) + f'(x) = 0$

we still need to establish the existence of the limits !

Another way is using the [Cauchy MVT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy.27s_mean_value_theorem).

For a $\epsilon > 0$, choose an an $\alpha > 0$, such that $\displaystyle |f(x) + f'(x)| \le \epsilon$, for $x \ge \alpha$.

Now Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem implies $\exists \beta \in (\alpha,x)$, such that

$$\displaystyle \dfrac{e^xf(x) - e^{\alpha}f({\alpha})}{e^x - e^{\alpha}} = f(\beta)+f'(\beta)$$

It follows that $|f(x) - f(a)e^{\alpha-x}| \le \epsilon|1-e^{\alpha-x}| \implies |f(x)| \le |f(\alpha)|e^{\alpha-x}+\epsilon|1-e^{\alpha-x}|$

Hence, $|f(x)| \le 2\epsilon$, for large enough $x$.

Comment: you need to first of all prove that the limit $L$ exists. (If it does, then it is easy, of $L\not=0$, say $L<0$, then $f'\to -L>0$ then from some point on $f$ is increasing with rate at least $-L/2$, so $f$ would have to go to $\infty$, a contradiction).

Comment: is there another method? ...without $e^x$

Comment: @HakoonaMatata yes .. it was proposed by Hardy in AMM a long time ago .. see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/842293/195458)

Comment: @sciona didn't get that... how do I show it?

Comment: @HakoonaMatata edited another approach.

Comment: Where does $2\epsilon$ in the last line come from .

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah choose $x$ large enough such that $|f(\alpha)|e^{\alpha - x} < \epsilon$.

Comment: @sciona Yes i see. thanks a lot. God bless you from Covid-19.

Answer (score 5):

If $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x) + f'(x) = 0$, then for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists
$y > 0$ such that for all $x > y$,

$$\begin{align}
& f(x) + f'(x) \le \epsilon\\
\implies & \frac{d}{dx}\big[f(x) e^x\big] = (f(x)+f'(x)) e^x \le \epsilon e^x\\
\implies & f(x)e^x - f(y)e^y = \int_y^x \frac{d}{dt}\big[f(t)e^t\big]dt \le \epsilon \int_y^x e^t dt = \epsilon( e^x - e^y)\\
\implies & f(x) \le \epsilon + ( f(y) - \epsilon ) e^{y-x}\\
\end{align}
$$
This leads to 
$$\limsup_{x\to+\infty} f(x) \le \epsilon + |f(y)-\epsilon|\lim_{x\to+\infty} e^{y-x} = \epsilon \tag{*1a}$$

Apply exactly the same argument to $-f(x)$, we get

$$\limsup_{x\to+\infty} ( -f(x) ) \le \epsilon\quad\implies\quad
\liminf_{x\to+\infty} f(x) \ge -\epsilon \tag{*1b}$$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, $(*1a)$ and $(*1b)$ together implies

$$0 = 
\underbrace{\sup_{\epsilon>0} (-\epsilon ) \le \liminf_{x\to+\infty} f(x)}_{(*1b)}
\;\le\;
\underbrace{\limsup_{x\to+\infty}f(x) \le \inf_{\epsilon > 0}\epsilon}_{(*1a)}
= 0
\quad\implies\quad
\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = 0\\
$$

Answer (score 2):

This was already posted on the site, but here we go: consider the function $g$ defined by $$g(x)=\mathrm e^xf(x),$$ then $$g'(x)=\mathrm e^x(f'(x)+f(x)),$$ hence, by hypothesis, for every positive $\varepsilon$, for every $x$ large enough, say, every $x\geqslant x_\varepsilon$, $$|g(x)|\leqslant\varepsilon\mathrm e^x.$$ Integrating this on the interval $(x_\varepsilon,x)$, one gets $$|g(x)|\leqslant|g(x_\varepsilon)|+\varepsilon(\mathrm e^x-\mathrm e^{x_\varepsilon})\leqslant|g(x_\varepsilon)|+\varepsilon\mathrm e^x,$$ for every $x\geqslant x_\varepsilon$, that is, $$|f(x)|\leqslant\varepsilon+|g(x_\varepsilon)|\mathrm e^{-x}.$$
When $x\to+\infty$, this yields $$\limsup_{x\to+\infty}|f(x)|\leqslant\varepsilon.$$ This upper bound holds for every positive $\varepsilon$ hence $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}|f(x)|=0.$$

Comment: Hi Didier.  You meant $|g'(x)|\le \varepsilon e^x$, not $|g(x)|\le \varepsilon e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that we can, from the limit, for any $\varepsilon>0$ we can write that, for all large enough $x$ tht
$$-\varepsilon< f(x)+f'(x)<\varepsilon$$
which can be written as
$$-\varepsilon-f(x) < f'(x) < \varepsilon-f(x)$$
which, as a simple bound, implies that if $f(x)>2\varepsilon$ then $f'(x)<-\varepsilon$. This means that $f$, for large enough $x$, is definitely eventually going to less than $2\varepsilon$. You can expand this into a full proof that the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists and is $0$ easily.

Answer (score 0):

Remarks: 1. I was supposed to answer this problem (2020/04/20) but was closed: [Prove if $\lim_{x\to +\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=0$ then $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633736/prove-if-lim-x-to-inftyfxfx-0-then-lim-x-to-infty-fx-0)

2. The usual L'Hopital's rule for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$
   does not work **directly** for the problem since one has to prove that
   $\lim_{x\to \infty} \mathrm{e}^xf(x) = \infty$.
3. It seems the following version of L'Hopital's rule is not used **directly** in the answers here. So I wrote down this answer.
4. The usual L'Hopital's rule deals with $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.
   As a discrete version of L'Hopital's rule, the Stolz-Cesaro theorem deals with $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\cdot}{\infty}$.
   Why doesn't the usual L'Hopital'rule deal with $\frac{\cdot}{\infty}$ like the Stolz-Cesaro theorem?

$\phantom{2}$

**Proof**

We will use the following version of L'Hopital's rule (page 3 in [1]):

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are differentiable on an open interval $I$ except possibly at a point $A$
contained in $I$, $g'(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$ in $I$, $\lim_{x\to A} g(x) = \infty$,
and $\lim_{x\to A} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L$. Then:
$$\lim_{x\to A} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L.$$
(Remark: Nothing is assumed about $\lim_{x\to A} f(x)$, not even its existence.)

$\phantom{2}$

By using L'Hopital's rule above,
since $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(\mathrm{e}^x f(x))'}{(\mathrm{e}^x)'}
= \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) + f'(x) = 0$
and $\lim_{x\to \infty} \mathrm{e}^x = \infty$,
we have $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\mathrm{e}^x f(x)}{\mathrm{e}^x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0$.
We are done.

*Reference*

[1] Gabriel Nagy, [https://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/snippets/stolz-cesaro.pdf](https://www.math.ksu.edu/%7Enagy/snippets/stolz-cesaro.pdf)

Comment: L'Hospital's Rule works on the forms "$0/0$" and "$\text{anything} /\infty $" but somehow the textbooks don't emphasize on the second form. Instead they write it as $\infty/\infty $. The only reason for this is that many textbook authors don't know the proof of the rule for second case.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Thank you. Many years ago, I saw its extension (Suppose $f''(x)$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty} f+f'+f'' = L$.
Prove that $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = L$.) I did not realize that we can not apply the usual L'Hopital's rule from the textbook **directly** which requires $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: See the relevant thread https://math.stackexchange.com/q/726027/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh   Thank you. The solutions in that link seem high level. It seems that one may simply apply L'Hopital rule for $\text{anything} /\infty$ similarly to solve it.

Comment: Well the technique of L'Hospital's Rule also works in exactly the same manner by first factoring $x^2+x+1=(x-w)(x-w^2)$ and then using functions $g=e^{-wx} f$ and $h=e^{-w^2x}g$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  Well, the approach of using L'Hopital's rule for $\frac{\cdot}{\infty}$ is simple and nice.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh  The solution in that link requires the continuity of $f''$? Can it be avoided? By the way, the approach of using L'Hopital's rule for $\frac{\cdot}{\infty}$ does not require the continuity of $f''$.