# Limit on a continuous differential equation

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function and let $L=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))$ be finite.

Does this imply that if $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$$
exists, then it is equal to $0$?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42277/limit-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-as-x-goes-to-infinity).

Comment: You can see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1039864/) as well !

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is because if $f'(x) > C>0$ for all $x>M$, then $f(x)$ goes to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: Also it appears that the extra hypothesis that $f'$ must have a limit as $x\to\infty$ can be dropped, since one can prove that from the fact that $f+f'$ has the limit $L$ (see linked thread).